# How to create a telnet connection through Serial port?

Tags: java, serial-port, telnet

I am trying to establish a telnet connection through a serial port in java. I am able to write to the port and confirmed that the data is written to the port using Serial port monitoring tool.

But I don't receive any response in turn.

I am using Java Simple Serial Connection Library/Jar (JSSC.jar)

Can anyone shed some light on this.

Comment: Please post what you have tried?

Comment: This question does not make sense.  Telnet is an internet protocol.  How can you possibly make an internet connection over a serial port?

Comment: Hi Stephen,
I need to communicate with a Cisco router which is configured with a Frame Relay Connection. My objective is to establish a telnet connection to the remote machine which resides at the other end of frame relay.
Steps which I have followed
1.Cisco router is connected with a serial port - So I tried connecting to that port and tried to open a telnet connection from Cisco router. The thing is I can write to this port but not getting any response from router.

Comment: I need to establish telnet session via Cisco router and not through Serial Port. I needed to communicate to router via serial port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Java Simple Serial Connection Jar and established a telnet session by the following steps:

1. Connect to Cisco router
2. fired the telnet command `ciscorouter>telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx xxxx /source-interface ethernetX`
3. Once telnet opened just fired my request query and recieved the response.

Note: For writing, I use:

```
    serialPort.writeString("command\r");`
```

and:

```
    byte buffer[] = null;
    String  s = new String(buffer);
```

Did not implement listeners as it caused lot of confusion.

Comment: I had to establish telnet session via the Cisco router. Not via Serial Port